# Actualizar tabla despues de eliminar y agregar registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un SP el cual me ejecuta dos instrucciones:

1. Eliminar todos los datos de 5 tablas
2. Agregar nuevos datos a esas 5 tablas

Cabe mencionar que son varios cientos de miles de registros que se eliminan y agregan, lo que quiero es tener un control de cuantos registros elimino de cada tabla y cuantos fueron los nuevos registros agregados a cada una de ellas.

He leido que se puede hacer con un Triguers, pero no se si el triguer actuara por cada registro eliminado y por cada registro que se inserte en la BDD, si esto es asi esto afectaria el rendimiento del servidor, repito son varios cientos de miles de datos.

Entonces si es un Triger, tendria que hacer un Triger por cada tabla?
o seria mejor hacer un update antes de eliminar y despues de agregar los registros, igual despues de ejecutar cada sentencia del SP?

Este es parte de mi SP:

```
IF (@num>6)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN TRAN1
            IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PLANT) as 'QtyPlants' FROM [CONEX]..[RPTDBA].[TW])=20
            TRUNCATE TABLE TIDV10A
            INSERT INTO [GSD_Sys].[dbo].[TIDV10A]
            SELECT * FROM [CONEX]..[RPTDBA].[TW]
            PRINT 'TIDV10A has been import.....'
            SET @num -=1;
        COMMIT TRAN TRAN1;
    END TRY
        
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT >0)
            ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END CATCH
END


IF (@num>5)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN TRAN2
            IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PLANT) as 'QtyPlants' FROM [CONEX]..[RPTDBA].[TX])=20
            TRUNCATE TABLE TIDV10B
            INSERT INTO [GSD_Sys].[dbo].[TIDV10B]
            SELECT * FROM [CONEX]..[RPTDBA].[TX]
            PRINT 'TIDV10B has been import.....'
            SET @num -=1;
        COMMIT TRAN TRAN2;
    END TRY
        
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT >0)
            ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END CATCH
END
```

Y esta es la tabla donde quiero almacernar los cambios:

```
CREATE TABLE TLHISTORY(
    historyId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    tName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,--Nombre de la tabla
    rowsDelete INT NOT NULL,--Registros eliminados
    rowsInsert INT NOT NULL,--Registros agregados
    uDate DATE NOT NULL
)
```

Hice estos cambios, pero no hago uso de OutputInserted, no se si es lo mejor o ya que no pude adaptar el codigo de propuesto por @Javi fer2 de da errores en las lineas de Inserted.Id y la variable @rowsBorrar no la reconoce.

Este es el ajuste que hice:

```
SELECT @rowsBorrar = COUNT(*) FROM TIDV10A;

            TRUNCATE TABLE TIDV10A; -- truncamos la tabla pero ya tenemos el número de filas.

            INSERT INTO [GSD_Sys].[dbo].[TIDV10A]
            SELECT * FROM [GSDAPPS].[dbo].[T56W];
            
            Select @rowsInsertadas = count(*) from [GSD_Sys].[dbo].[TIDV10A]

            Insert into TLHISTORY(tName, rowsDelete, rowsInsert, uDate) 
                Values ('TIDV10A',@rowsBorrar,@rowsInsertadas,getdate());
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos

DS

Comment: los triggers se manejan por tablas. Quieres obtener el total de registros borrados y agregados? crea una variable y ve sumando los eliminados y agregados. quieres por tablas? puedes usar triggers o más variables en el sp

Comment: Te falta hacer Declare rowsBorrar int; Declare rowsInsertadas int; Por eso te da error, ya que no has declarado las variables. Antenponiendo la arroba a los nombres de variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas utilizar ***triggers***, ya que todos los datos, los puedes calcular en el propio *procedure*. Además si creas *triggers* en las tablas de origen, estos se disparan por cada sentencia de inserción o borrado en cada una de las tablas, y no solo con las que llame este procedimiento.

Dado que el código de ambos `IF` es básicamente el mismo, te planteo la solución en uno de ellos.

```
IF (@num>6)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN TRAN1
            IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PLANT) as 'QtyPlants' FROM [CONEX]..[RPTDBA].[TW])=20
                Declare @rowsBorrar int;
                Declare @tbl_TlHistory table (id int);
                Declare @rowsInsertadas int;

                Select @rowsBorrar = Count(*) from TIDV10A;


                TRUNCATE TABLE TIDV10A; -- truncamos la tabla pero ya tenemos el número de filas.

                INSERT INTO [GSD_Sys].[dbo].[TIDV10A]
                Output inserted.id into @rowsBorrar 
                SELECT * FROM [CONEX]..[RPTDBA].[TW];
                
                Select @rowsInsertadas = count(*) from @tbl_TlHistory;

                Insert into TlHistory(tName, rowsDelete, rowsInsert, uDate) 
                    Values ('[GSD_Sys].[dbo].[TIDV10A]',@salida,@rowsInsertadas,getdate());
                
                PRINT 'TIDV10A has been import.....';
                SET @num -=1;
        COMMIT TRAN TRAN1;
    END TRY
        
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT >0)
            ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END CATCH
END
```

Las variables de @rowsBorrar y @rowsInsertadassolo tienes que declararlas una vez. Lo mismo con la variable tipo Tabla @tbl_TlHistory, pero esta además tienes que, cada vez que la uses borrar su contenido.

El funcionamiento es:

Contar las rows que vas a truncar en la siguiente instrucción. Luego utilizamos Output de la tabla a insertar para recoger los ids en la variable de tabla. Estos ids, nos permitirán saber cuantas rows se insertan. Es posible que fuera suficiente con hacer un count de las filas que se leen en *[CONEX]..[RPTDBA].[TW]*, pero eso es algo que tienes que decidir tú.

Una vez que se ha insertado, simplemente contamos lo insertado y ya realizamos la inserción en la tabla de history.

[Cláusula Output en insert](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/09/01/clausula-output-en-insert/)

Comment: Estoy intentando usar tu codigo @Javie fer2, pero obtengo error el la variable "@rowsBorrar", el error es el siguiente:
Must declare the table variable "@rowsBorrar", la declare y de igual forma de da error.
Una cosa mas la variable "@salida" de donde sale? asumo que los valores en la insercción son tableName, recordsDelete, recordsInsert y fecha.

Comment: De igual forma el id en la clausula inserted no me la reconoce. @Javi fer2

Comment: Si lo has solucionado leyendo antes de insertar, no te cuento más. Pero inserted. algo es la columna identificador de la tabla a la que se inserta. Puede ser que TID0VA no tenga columna id

Comment: Gracias @Javi fer2 ha quedado solucionado.